# Using memtier_benchmark; every key is missed

Tags: redis

My misses/sec are populated and there are no hits.

Data contains keys range from 1 to 300 K and data stored is string type

```
memtier_benchmark -s xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p xxxxx -P redis -t 1 -n 1 --ratio 0:1 -c 1 -x 2 --key-pattern S:S --authenticate=xxxxxxx --key-prefix=
```

Comment: Data contains keys range from 1 to 300 K and data stored is string type

Answer (score 6):

`memtier_benchmark` is pretty poorly documented in this regard. If you use it out of the box on first run, it won't simulate any cache hits, which is pretty useless in terms of a tool designed to test cache performance.

The 2 key parameters here are:

```
--key-pattern=[SET:GET]
--ratio=[SET:GET]
```

`--key-pattern` defines the names given to keys that are set and the names of keys requested. For instance, if you use `S:S`, that means that the software will set the first key as `memtier-0` and then immediately request `memtier-1`, then set `memtier-1`, then request `memtier-2` (Go figure...). That's why you get a 100% miss result.

If you set `R:R`, that means the software will randomly set the digit in the keyname in both the Set and the Get. This will typically result in a miss ratio of > 90%, depending on how many clients and threads you set. If you're operating a cache with a miss ratio of > 90%, it's questionable whether or not you should be running a cache at all, so again, this is pretty useless.

To simulate what a real world cache should be doing, you want to have a miss ratio of < 50%. To achieve this, you need to expand the number of Gets over Sets. The default for `memtier_benchmark` is `1:10`, but again, on first run (or if you're persistently running this against a cold cache) with `--key-pattern=S:S` as default, you're still going to get a very high miss ratio. If you keep repeating the test against the same cache you are continually populating, you should see your miss ratio begin to fall, but again, that may not be something you can rely on if you're testing in an ephemeral environment.

To get a lower miss ratio on a first run, I use:

```
--key-pattern=S:R --ratio=1:20
```

This should result in a miss ratio < 50%. That's as good as I've been able to simulate. My actual cache will have a miss ratio of < 5%. I'm still trying to figure out a way to test that with `memtier_benchmark`.

Also, use `--hide-histogram` to get rid of the annoying dump of test results.

---

EDIT:

For a full blown 100% hit / 0% miss ratio, do the following:

Start with a cold, empty cache

Run a test that uses the `-ratio=` parameter so that only `Sets` are included in the test, in a very narrow key range:

```
--hide-histogram --key-pattern=S:S --key-minimum=1 --key-maximum=50 --ratio=1:0
```

Now, run the test again, and this time, flip the ratio so that only `Gets` are included:

```
--hide-histogram --key-pattern=S:S --key-minimum=1 --key-maximum=50 --ratio=0:1
```

You can then tune the hit/miss ratio by re-running both parts and expanding the `--key-maximum=` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your ratio is `0 set add 1 get`. change it to `1:1` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate your memcached before trying a read-only benchmark.

To populate it, you can run a write-only workload to write all the keys at least once.